# Cannot make Python WMI work even with Admin User

Tags: python, wmi, wmic

I have been using Python's WMI for quite some time and I use Python elevate to handle services. However, I have run into trouble with Robot Framework's IDE (RIDE), which terminates due to elevate.elevate() as the Python interpreter is launched again with Admin rights and RIDE believes that the test has been interrupted.

I'm on a local machine and all the users that run Robot FW, have admin rights and UAC is OFF. I figured out that I might need "impersonation" while init'ing the wmi object, but having tried the following, I cannot get anything done, unless I "take" admin rights.

Here is all what I tried:

```
#
# Tried impersonation delegate. Used a moniker from various sources, but they don't work too.
#

wmi_obj = wmi.WMI(impersonation_level="Impersonate", privileges=["SystemProfile", "MachineAccount", "Security"])

class ManageServiceException(Exception) :
    pass

def GetServiceInfo(service_name) :
    """
    Get information about the service(s) whose name matches with the _service_name_.
    Return an object of the service, if found or raise an exception.
    Eg: obj.State
    """
    global wmi_obj
    #elevate.elevate(show_console=False) # tried show_console=True and False
    try:
        return wmi_obj.Win32_Service(Name=service_name)
    except:
        raise ManageServiceException("No service found with name %s"% service_name)
```

I can control services in services.msc without having to "Run as Admin". I want to do the same here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the correct solution:

```
wmi_obj = wmi.WMI(moniker="winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2", impersonation_level="Impersonate")
```